# Why does adding a method to the Array prototype in javascript break iteration on a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'm working in a large legacy codebase and just realized that someone did this:

```
Array.prototype.insertAt = function (i,el){ return this.splice(i,0,el); }
Array.prototype.deleteAt = function (i){return this.splice(i, 1); }
```

and that this is the reason i can't to this:

```
var derp = new Array();
derp.push('duh');
derp.push('what?');

for (var i in derp) {
    console.log(derp[i]);
}
```

Well, it's not that i can't do it, but if i do, i get unexpected results.  That being instead of getting two lines of output (for 'duh' and 'what?') i get four.  the last two being the two functions listed above.

I don't want to remove the original prototype functions (because god knows what depends on them), but i am wondering if there is a way to prevent the for loop from looping over the functions that were added.

Comment: `for..in` is purposed to iterate objects. Use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: Agree with using for loops - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: I like both of these comments better than any of the official answers because i learned that i shouldn't be using for .. in in the first place.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1: Use a regular for (best supported)

```
for(var i=0;i<derp.length;i++){
    console.log(derp[i])
}
```

Method 2: Use hasOwnProperty

```
for(var i in arr){
 if(arr.hasOwnProperty(i)){
     console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Method 3: Use Object.defineProperty:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'insertAt', {
    writeable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Array.prototype.insertAt
})
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'deleteAt', {
    writeable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: Array.prototype.deleteAt
})

for(var i in derp){
    console.log(derp[i])
}
```

Which one you use depends on your browser support, last one prevents changing all for code written though

Comment: The third method is perfect, this is exactly what i originally wanted. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use .forEach to iterate over an array or a regular for loop. for in is meant for object iteration and will include all properties on the prototype (which is why Object.keys(obj).forEach is preferred for object iteration as it does a hasOwnProperty check internally)

Comment: You're not considering legacy browser support for this method. This method is not available prior to IE9.

Comment: @JacobHeater: Just use a polyfill.

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're overcomplicating the solution.

Comment: a regular for loop isn't available prior to IE9? I believe I gave two options in my answer, and expounded upon enumerable prototype properties. OP has every ability to look further into each one of the methods listed.

Comment: @gabdallah Apologies! I should've read the answer more carefully. Correction: The Array.prototype.forEach method is not available prior to IE9. A for loop, of course, is!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i in derp) {
    if(derp.hasOwnProperty(i)) 
        console.log(derp[i]);
}
```

But then, normal `for` loop is far better for `Array`  than using `for-in` (which is actually for Object)

```
for (var i = 0; i < derp.length; i++) { 
    console.log(derp[i]);
}
```